# How to handle multireddits with praw

Tags: python, reddit, praw

does anybody have any experience with handling multireddits with PRAW?

I need to get a list of multi's for a logged in user (that should be http://www.reddit.com/dev/api/oauth#GET_api_multi_mine) and then get a list of subbreddits in each multi.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this with PRAW.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented (yet).

You can send the requests through [get_content](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/master/praw/__init__.py#L401), which would allow you to take advantage of some of PRAW's features such as request throttling, caching and objects rather than json. It will still be some work.

I'll update this comment when multireddit functionality is implemented in PRAW.

Comment: Looks like there's something now: http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/multireddit.html. I'm still confused about it though, so a write up would be much appreciated :)